# Sikuli error : "get_keyword_names failed!"

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework, sikuli

im trying to test an app with robot Framework and Sikuli library on docker , but when i run test , im always recieve the same error : "Test get_keyword_names failed! Connecting remote server at http://127.0.0.1:37027/ failed: <Fault 0: 'Failed to invoke method get_keyword_names in class org.robotframework.remoteserver.servlet.ServerMethods: java.lang.RuntimeException'>"

here my test script : "

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     Test d'IHM par sikuli et robot framework
Library    SikuliLibrary    port=58301   timeout=3.0    mode=REMOTE

Suite Setup   Run Keywords  Start Sikuli Process  AND    Read Images From Path    AND     Open IHM Application
Suite Teardown   Run Keywords    Close Application     ${APP_PATH}    AND   Stop Remote Server

*** Variables ***
${IMAGES_PATH}        /app/SikuliImages.sikuli
${APP_PATH}           /app/FHF_App.exe

***Test Cases***
Open IHM
    Open IHM Application
Read Images
   Read Images From Path
Navigate IHM Application Buttons
    Navigate Buttons
*** Keywords ***
Read Images From Path 
     Add Image Path    ${IMAGES_PATH}
Open IHM Application
    Open Application    ${APP_PATH}
Navigate Buttons
     
    Wait Until Screen Contain     pauseButtonPull.png   timeout=30
    Click    pauseButtonPull.png
    Wait Until Screen Contain     pausePanel.png    timeout=40 
    
    Click    pauseButtonDown.png
    Click    PexpButtonPull.png
    Wait Until Screen Contain    PexpPanel.png    timeout=10
    Click    PexpButtonDown.png"
```

---

---

here you find my dockerfile image : "

```
# Utilisez une image de base adoptopenjdk pour Java 8
FROM adoptopenjdk:8-jdk-hotspot

# Installez les dépendances requises pour SikuliLibrary, OpenCV et Tesseract
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libasound2 libc6-i386 libc6-x32 libxext6 libxi6 libxrender1 libxtst6 libopencv-dev tesseract-ocr

# Téléchargez SikuliX
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget https://launchpad.net/sikuli/sikulix/2.0.5/+download/sikulixide-2.0.5-lux.jar 

# Créez le répertoire SikuliX
RUN mkdir -p /root/.Sikulix/SikulixStore/

# Installez Python et Robot Framework
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install robotframework robotframework-sikulilibrary

# Définissez le répertoire de travail
WORKDIR /app

# Copiez votre code et vos ressources dans le conteneur
COPY . /app

# Exposez le port Sikuli (changez le port 4119 si nécessaire)
EXPOSE 4119

# Exécutez votre code ou vos tests avec Robot Framework
CMD ["sh", "-c", "x11vnc -forever -usepw -create & robot hello.robot"]
```

"

Comment: You should try to use Java 11.